# Pixel RGB values are all 255 after converting from byte[]

Tags: c#, bitmap

I have a `byte[]` for an image, which was read directly from the image itself, and I am trying to convert this byte[] into a `Bitmap` object.

I am using the code:

```
var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
var multipart = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).ContinueWith(t => {
    foreach (var item in provider.Contents) {

        var filename = item.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('\"');
        var buffer = item.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

        MemoryStream mss = new MemoryStream(buffer.Result);
        Bitmap bmpImage = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(mss);

        //bmpImage.GetPixel(10,10) returns ARGB values of 255,255,255,255

    }
});
```

However, when I call `bmpImage.GetPixel(10,10)`, the ARGB values are `255,255,255,255`. This makes no sense to me. Does anyone have any ideas why this conversion could be causing a loss of my pixel information?

The above code is wrapped in the `ApiController` `Post()` method:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
```

Comment: What format is the source?

Comment: Your buffer, is it raw pixel values? Image.FromStream expects a format like PNG or JPEG, etc.

Comment: I added the rest of my code showing where it comes from. The data is read directly from a POSTed image. I checked the values in a Hex editor, and the `byte[]` does have correct byte values for the image. But for some reason it's still not converting correctly.

Comment: Shouldn't you be inspecting `t.Result`? I have no experience with those types so I might be wrong, but that's what I would expect.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen `buffer.Result` gives the `byte[]` that I'm interested in converting to a `Bitmap`. `t.Result` points to the `MultipartMemoryStreamProvider` instance.

Comment: @Brett I meant instead of `provider.Contents`. It looks like there's a dependence on the mutability of the class. Wouldn't it be better practice, at least, to use `t.Result.Contents`? Again, I'm not familiar with these classes. But it sure doesn't look like a regular design pattern as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing:

```
var buffer = item.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
MemoryStream mss = new MemoryStream(buffer.Result);
Bitmap bmpImage = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(mss);
```

with:

```
Stream stream = item.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
Bitmap bmpImage = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(stream);
```

did the trick. I don't initally see the why the second works and the first doesn't, but the `ReadAsStreamAsync()` call works and the `ReadAsByteArrayAsync()` doesn't.